# xbindkeys, xvkbd, and Firefox

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox, xbindkeys

I'm trying to map `alt+j` to the down key and it's working everywhere but Firefox.

In `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\[Down]""
  alt + j
```

then with `xbindkeys` running, `alt+j` has various effects in Firefox depending on the context. In the address bar, where pressing the down key would select the next auto-complete option, the address bar flashes and the cursor goes to the end. On most pages it scrolls down as normal. In text boxes it goes to the next line down. In Google Docs the page scrolls down instead of the cursor going to the next line. According to https://www.toptal.com/developers/keycode the down key is being received in JS but with the shift key briefly pressed first.

Any suggestions on how to debug the issue or ideas for alternative ways to remap key combinations that works in all applications would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a mistake in the syntax, I also had difficulty with this syntax, perhaps part of the documentation is obsolete.
Try to imitate this syntax: `(xbindkey '("m:0x4" "c:41") "xterm") )` 
This is for "set directly keycode (here control + f with my keyboard)
"